# Streaming from elasticsearch to local file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-rest

I have a large Document in elasticsearch(deployed in server) and i want get that document and store in local file without give more load on JVM- using streaming.
Is it doable or not, if yes how?
for example- in elasticsearch, Document size is 1GB and i have 500MB free memory available in JVM and i want few MB to be used out of 500MB in process.

Comment: Don't use a Java application for that. Use Logstash, which is part of the ELK stack

Comment: Appreciated much, this is the current scenario i am in which so, Still searching

Comment: "Is it doable" ? Sure it is. Elasticsearch interacts primarily on HTTP (which is streaming friendly), and file writing also. "How", well by connecting the HTTP stream (or Channel if using NIO) to the file stream (or channel if using NIO). But I guess if you are asking, it's probably not clear to you. May we ask how do you connect to elasticsearch ? Through its Java (high level ? low level ?) client ? Through Spring Data Elastic ? ...

Comment: public class ElasticSearch extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {
 @Autowired
 MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
 @GetMapping(value = "/getABC")
 public String savePersone() throws IOException {
   SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
   ssb.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("xxxx", "xxxx"));
   String[] indices = {new String("xxxx")};
   SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indices , ssb);
   searchRequest.source(ssb);
   SearchResponse response = elasticsearchClient().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
  return "Success";
 }

Comment: @Override
 public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
  ClientConfiguration cc = ClientConfiguration.builder()
    .connectedTo("xx.xx.xxx.xx:XXXX")
    .build();
  return RestClients.create(cc).rest();
 }

}

Comment: Above two comments- are for exact java code, by which i am getting record in shot , but i need in stream